# How to override properties load from file with properties load from database in ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring

My web application is using spring and some of the bean properties are load by using ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. And the properties are in the file system. However, I want to have some of the property to be loaded from database. And the property from database will override the one in the file system if there are duplicate.

I found this method in ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(Properties properties). But Spring documentation said that the property from file will override it. I want the other way around. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: The solution is that I have to load database configuration manually by  having the setter for jdbc url, username, password. Then read the table to create a properties object. Then I can use the localOverride = true with the method setProperties(Properties dbProperties). Then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the behaviour by setting the `localOverride` property to `true`.  From the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setLocalOverride%28boolean%29):

> Set whether local properties override properties from files. Default
>   is "false": Properties from files override local defaults. Can be
>   switched to "true" to let local properties override defaults from
>   files.

Comment: I ran into seems like a circular property dependency. My property bean that needed to load from database depends on the dataSource bean which is also has db configuration as property. And Spring couldn't load the dataSource bean correctly because the ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer hasn't been load to the end yet. Do you know how to get around that problem?